# How to show two linear programs are equivalent?

Tags: linear-programming

We know that 1-norm is defined as $\|v \|_1 = |v_{1}| + \dots + |v_{n}|$ for the vector $v = \left(v_1, \dots, v_n\right)^T$. Suppose we have

program (a)

$$
  \min\limits_{x} \|Ax-b\|_1
$$

and program (b)

$$
  \min\limits_{u,x} e^{T}u
$$
$$
\text{subject to} -u\le Ax-b \le u,
$$

where $ e = (1, \dots, 1)^{T} $.

How to prove program (a) and program (b) are equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proof: Write (b) in the following equivalent form,

$$
  \min\limits_{x}(\min\limits_u e^T u),
$$
$$
\text{subject to} -u\le Ax-b \le u.
$$

where the minimization of $u$ is over a fixed $x$. For any $y$, $-u\le y\le u \Longleftrightarrow |y|\le u \implies e^T|y|\le e^T u$. For a given $x$, $u=|Ax-b|$ satisfies the constraint, and by the previous sentence, minimizes the inner minimization problem, i.e. $\min\limits_u e^T u$ under $-u\le Ax-b \le u$. Therefore, problem (b) is equivalent to
$$
  \min\limits_{x} e^{T}|Ax-b|
$$

which is (a).

Comment: Thank you for your post. Can I ask why it is equivalent to $\min\limits_{x} e^{T} |Ax-b|$?

Comment: @SmithBlack: I have added the detail of the equivalence. Is it clear enough?